# Просьба оценить безопасность подхода

Tags: javascript

Через `ajax` я получаю с сервера некие данные, генерировать которые там может абсолютно любой пользователь.

Данные эти я в одностраничном ***js-приложении*** (которое оперирует токенами и паролями!) вывожу во фрейм и ещё в кучу мест через `.innerHTML`.

Перед выводом я везде заменяю символы `', ", <, >, &` на их `html-`представление. Достаточного ли этого для избежания потенциальной js-инъекции и прочего?

Одну переменную я также вывожу из коллекции контроллера `angularjs` через `{{...}}`.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что тут на выходе простой текст и такой вывод безопасен и без замены символов?

Comment: Зачем innerHTML, когда есть textContent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через свойство `innerText` будет надёжней. И самому не надо делать замены спецсимволов

```js
let someBadText = `<div>DIV</div>`

{// https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText
    let el = document.createElement('div')
    el.innerText = someBadText
    document.body.appendChild(el)
}

{// https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText
    let el = document.createElement('div')
    el.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', someBadText)
    document.body.appendChild(el)
}
```

Comment: @Air почему не является?

Comment: Благодарю. innerHTML был нужен по той причине, что к данным добавлялся ещё и html-код, который должен был быть включён в страницу именно как код. Но сейчас переписал логику, теперь textContent. Спасибо.